# OpenCV3.0 With Qt creator 3.2 & Qt 5.4 build error "mingw32-make: *** [Makefile] Error 3"

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, makefile

I have compiled OpenCV 3.0 with Qt5.4 & Qt Creator 3.2 64 bits in a Windows 7 machine.

I have been trying to execute the most basic OpenCV functionalaty in loading a picture. Unfortunately it gives the following error:

> > C:\Qt\qt-5.4.0-x64-mingw492r0-sjlj\qt-5.4.0-x64-mingw492r0-sjlj\bin\qmake.exe
> >     -spec win32-g++ CONFIG+=release -o Makefile ..\opencv_xpto\opencv_xpto.pro C:/Users/Nelson
> >     Faria/Documents/Programacao/opencv_xpto/opencv_xpto.pro:14: Extra
> >     characters after test expression. Error processing project file:
> >     ..\opencv_xpto\opencv_xpto.pro makefile:175: recipe for target
> >     'Makefile' failed mingw32-make: *** [Makefile] Error 3 20:53:17: The
> >     process
> >     "C:\Qt\qt-5.4.0-x64-mingw492r0-sjlj\mingw64\bin\mingw32-make.exe"
> >     exited with code 2. Error while building/deploying project opencv_xpto
> >     (kit: Qt 5.4) When executing step "Make" 20:53:17: Elapsed time:
> >     00:01.

The code I'm trying to execute is the following:

```
   '#include <iostream>
    #include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
    #include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
    #include "opencv/cv.h"

    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
        cout << "Hello World!" << endl;

        cv::Mat mat;
        mat = cv::imread("img.JPG");
        cv::namedWindow("hello");
        cv::imshow("hello",mat);

        cv::waitKey(0);

        return 0;
    }
```

And finally the .pro

```
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= app_bundle
CONFIG -= qt

SOURCES += main.cpp

INCLUDEPATH += C:\opencv-mingw\install\include
LIBS += -LC:\\opencv-mingw\\install\\x64\mingw\\lib
    -lopencv_core300.dll \
    -lopencv_highgui300.dll \
    -lopencv_imgproc300.dll \
    -lopencv_features2d300.dll \
    -lopencv_calib3d300.dll

include(deployment.pri)
qtcAddDeployment()'
```

Can someone inlight me where I gone wrong?

Comment: in Qt project file don't use back slashes! Use slashes as directory separator (it doesn't meter that this is windows).

Comment: Hi thanks, for the feedback. I have made the changes you have suggested. Even so it eliminated the initial error it has generated a different one this time:

C:\Users\Nelson Faria\Documents\Programacao\opencvTest02\main.cpp:-1: error: undefined reference to `cv::imread(cv::String const&, int)'

collect2.exe:-1: error: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Any idea what may be?

Comment: try omit extensions for libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct pro file like that:

```
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= app_bundle
CONFIG -= qt

SOURCES += main.cpp

INCLUDEPATH += C:/opencv-mingw/install/include
LIBS += -LC:/opencv-mingw/install/x64/mingw/lib
    -lopencv_core300 \
    -lopencv_highgui300 \
    -lopencv_imgproc300 \
    -lopencv_features2d300 \
    -lopencv_calib3d300

include(deployment.pri)
qtcAddDeployment()
```

---

If you have a crash it is most probable that application is unable to load openCV dlls. There are two ways to fix this:

- copy those dlls to directory with your executable (most probaly more or less something like that: `<your roject location>\..\debug-windows-64x-qt5-XXX`
- add to the path variable location of those dlls

Comment: Thanks that has improved and solved the previous error. But again I have another new erro :(
exited with code -1073741515
Any ideas what is the problem now???
:(